# Conversion Tool

Tags: sharepoint-addin, conversion

I'm trying to create a conversion tool/app in SharePoint where users can put in a Julian Date and it spits out the actual date as a result. I don't want this something that is saved as a list, and for the life of me, I can't figure out what I need to add.

I've created a couple fake columns as a sample in a pre-existing form, and my formula checks out, but it's currently in a list, and I want people with READ ONLY access to access a separate SharePoint page, type in a string of numbers, and for the conversion to apply and show the correct date.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to implement this would be to use a Script Editor web part and just create a very basic HTML input with some JavaScript. Then you can put it wherever. There are several examples online of the necessary JavaScript to make this conversion.

Comment: I've tried some REALLY basic JavaScript, but I don't think security allows for it because it's stripping out some things, and the one thing I *did* get to work, it would auto-refresh the page. This is on a secure site, and I don't control security protocols for what is and isn't allowed on our browser, but it doesn't look like JavaScript is a solution from everything I've tried, and I'm not a strong enough programmer to create all of that on my own.

Comment: What was your code? Where did you put it?  Try putting just an alert inside the script editor web part.

Comment: (edited)
It was really elementary stuff I googled:

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<button onclick="Julian()">Click me</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function Julian() {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Hello World";
}
</script>

</body>
</html>

Clicking the button would show the text, but it refreshed and went away, immediately.

Comment: @WillDutcher try getting rid of the HTML and the body tags - the SharePoint page will already have those and the text editor won't like it when you try to save them to the page - for the refresh issue try using `<button type="button" onclick=...>` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1878264/how-do-i-make-an-html-button-not-reload-the-page and also try doing some more research :)

Comment: the '    type="button"...    ' solution is something I found in my research and it didn't seem to work. I'll try it in conjunction with removing the head/body tags and let you know. Thank you!